# Regex .match() not finding matches even though it should

Tags: node.js, regex

I'm trying to scan a .txt file in a node.js script, and scan its contents for certain pieces of data. The lines I'm interested in getting look mostly like this:

```
DIBH91643 5/10/2019 108,75
SIR108811 5/10/2019 187,50
SIR108845 5/10/2019 63,75
```

So I've been trying to match them with a regex without succes. Using a regex testing site, I've even confirmed the fact that it should find the matches I'm looking for, but it always returns null when I call data.match(regex). I'm probably missing something basic here, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. This is the code I'm using (in its entirety, since there isn't much):

```
var fs = require('fs');
let regex = /\w*?(\d+)\s+(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\s+(\-{0,1}\d+\,\d+)/g;
let ihateregex = /91/g;

fs.readFile('pathToFile/fileToRead.txt',{encoding: 'utf-8'}, (err, data) => {
  var result = data.match(regex);
  console.log(result);
});
```

As shown, even an attempt with a simple pattern that is definitely inside the file still returns null. I have looked into other answers here for similar problems, and they all point to deleting bytes from the beginning of the file. I have used vim -b to delete the first 2 bytes - which did look out of place and furthermore printing the entire data with console.log() did actually show 2 weird characters in the beginning of the file, but I get the exact same error.

I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Comment: This probably isn't right, but shouldn't `console.log(result);` have a reference to the group captured so, using your regex, `console.log(result[2]);` for the date?  Maybe, see https://regexr.com/51nc0

Comment: Since result returns null, result[2] returns an error of being called on null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally figured out what went wrong and I feel extremely stupid for taking so long to figure it out. One thing I've failed to mention even though I should have is that the file I'm reading is one created by an OCR program. An OCR program which, apparently, added an invisible char between each character in the text file, that I only saw when I switched to php (fopen(), fgets(), fclose()) and looked at the source of the page I made.

Once I copied the contents of fileToRead.txt into a newly created fileToRead2.txt (simple copy-paste), it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
/^[A-Z]*(\d+)\s+(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\s+(-?\d+,\d+)/gm
```

Improvements compared to your regex:

- `^` - start from the start of line,
- `[A-Z]*` instead of `\w*?` - note that *\w* matches also digits,
- removed `/` in front of `-` and `,`,
- `?` instead of `{0,1}`,
- added `m` option (I assume that you want to process all rows, not the first only).

To process the matches I used the following code, using *rextester.com*, so
instead of e.g. *console.log(...)* it contains *print(...)*:

```
let data = 'DIBH91643 5/10/2019 108,75\nSIR108811 5/10/2019 187,50\nSIR108845 5/10/2019 63,75'
print("Data: ")
print(data)
let re = /^[A-Z]*(\d+)\s+(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\s+(-?\d+,\d+)/gm
print("Result: ")
while ((matches = re.exec(data)) != null) {
    print(matches[1], '_', matches[2], '_', matches[3])
}
```

For a working example see https://rextester.com/PZU21213

Comment: Didn't work with that regex either, still returns null. Again; I've already tested the regex on regexr.com, and it worked. I've no idea what's going on.